# Mock a namespace and a function with same name using Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocking, jestjs

A library I'm using is structured as

```
declare namespace foo {
  function bar();
};

declare namespace foo.bar {
  function baz();
};
```

So the two functions I need to mock are `foo.bar()` and `foo.bar.baz()`.

To mock `foo.bar()` I was previously using

```
require('foo');

jest.mock('foo', () => ({
  bar: () => mockedBar,
}));
```

Is there any way to mock `foo.bar.baz()`? I tried

```
jest.mock('foo.bar', () => ({
}));
```

But it's showing a message `Cannot find module 'foo.bar' from 'functions.test.js'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a custom mock for your module in a `__mocks__` folder in your project root (defined in jest config!). So you can create `__mocks__/foo.js` with mocked `foo` module functions and Jest automatically loads this module for test purposes. Also you can specify custom path to your mock:

`jest.mock('foo', () => jest.requireActual('../some/another/folder/foo.js'));`

Check a [Jest manual](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) for more info

Answer (score 3):

If 'foo' is under global, you may try adding codes below in the beginning of test script. Or write them in a .js file in and import it in the first line.

```
Object.defineProperty(global, "foo", {
    value: {
        bar: {
            baz: ()=>{
                 return true;
               },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Or simply

```
global["foo"] = {
    bar: {
        baz: () => {
            return true;
        },
    },
};
```

to mock one.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this post is the main OP is quite old, but I will add the *mostly correct way* of doing this.

`namespace`s are nothing but raw JavaScript `Function` objects at the end and mocking these ends up being straightforward when you start thinking of a `namespace` as an object.

The following structure then:

```js
declare namespace foo {
  function bar();
};

declare namespace foo.bar {
  function baz();
};
```

can be mocked using *Jest* as follows:

```js
jest.mock('foo', () => {
  const bar = jest.fn().mockImplementation();
  bar.baz = jest.fn().mockImplementation();
  return {
    bar
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs using a dot inside of a name is fine, but I have a gut feeling against it.

I recommend you to nest the namespaces.

You can include the declaration of `bar` into `foo`

```
declare namespace foo {
  function bar();

  declare namespace bar {
    function baz();
  };

};
```

**Proof of concept**

foo.ts

```
export namespace foo {
    export function bar() { return "bar"}

    export namespace bar {
        function baz() { return "baz"}
    }
}
```

foo.test.ts

```
import {foo} from "./foo"

describe("jest-mock-namespace", () => {
    it("Should mock foo.bar to return whatever we want", () => {
        const WWW = "WHATEVER_WE_WANT";
        // @ts-ignore
        foo.bar = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce( () => WWW);

        const result = foo.bar();

        expect(result).toStrictEqual(WWW)
    });

    it("Should mock foo.bar.baz to return whatever we want", () => {
        const WWW = "WHATEVER_WE_WANT";
        // @ts-ignore
        foo.bar.baz = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce( () => WWW);

        // @ts-ignore
        const result = foo.bar.baz();

        expect(result).toStrictEqual(WWW)
    });
})
```